# Issue with routing to Areas Net Core 3 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to write a new web application. I have created a new Area called Company. In the area is a Controller, with a View which calls a View Component. The View Component has a form that I am trying to redirect to the HomeController (Add Action) within the Company Area. However it redirects to `localhost/Home/Add?area=Company` instead of `localhost/Company/Home/Add`

My Startup.cs where I define the routes

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           ...
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    areaName: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
```

The HomeController that provides the index page

```
    [Area("Company")]
    [Route("Company/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

        public HomeController(IRepositoryWrapper repository, IAppBiz biz, IEmailSender emailSender, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) : base(repository, biz, emailSender, userManager, httpContext)
        {

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

HomeController Index.cshtml calling the ViewComponent

```
<div class="container m-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("CompanyList", new { userID = 1 })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewComponent Default.cshtml with an "Add" button so I can add a new Company (It also gives a list of existing companies, removed for brevity.

```
     <form asp-area="Company" asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td class="align-middle">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it... in `Startup.cs`

```
  endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    areaName: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
```

should be

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "area",
                    areaName: "area",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Most of the documentation I've read stated "areas" and not "area."